# How can i display data (in form of events) from more than one tables or two tables in full calender simultaneously. in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I have data in two tables that are Leaves and HolidayLists, that I want to display on the full calendar but by the following code, I am getting data from only one table when I comment on one Ajax code otherwise nothing is displayed full calendar. in asp.net core MVC

```
events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    contentType: "application/json;",
                    url: "/LeaveManagement/GetHolidaysData",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var holidays = [];
                        $.each(data, function (i, data) {
                            holidays.push({
                                title: data.holidayName,
                                description: data.holidayName,
                                start: moment(data.date).add(1, 'days').format("MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss"),
                                end: moment(data.date).add(2, 'days').format("MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss"),
                                backgroundColor: 'red',
                                // borderColor: 'black',
                                textColor: 'White',
                                color: 'red',
                                id: data.id,


                            });
                        });
                        callback(holidays);
                    },
                }).done(function (data) {
                    console.log(data.result);
                }),

           $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        contentType: "application/json;",
                        url: "/LeaveManagement/GetLeaveData",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            var leaves = [];
                            $.each(data, function (i, data) {
                                leaves.push({
                                    title: data.userName,
                                    description: data.leaveType,
                                    start: moment(data.from).add(1, 'days').format("MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss"),
                                    end: moment(data.to).add(2, 'days').format("MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss"),
                                    backgroundColor: 'blue',
                                    // borderColor: 'black',
                                    textColor: 'White',
                                    color: 'blue',
                                    id: data.id,


                                });
                            });
                            callback(leaves);
                        }
                    }).done(function (data) {
                        console.log(data.result);
                    })

                },

            dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {

                $(document).ready(function () { $("#From").val(moment(date).format("DD-MM-YYYY")); });

            },
```

Comment: That seems like two different questions - you want from more than one table first and then go from there.

Comment: i am having two tables that is Leaves and HolidayLists, simply i want to display data  on full calendar from both table.

Comment: right now you are executing `callback` twice in two places, but this makes no sense. As soon as the first one is called, fullCalendar will render the events, and ignore anything else you do. Your options are either 1) add all the results into one array variable and then send that to `callback` **once** (for that you would probably need to chain your AJAX requests), or 2) make your server able to return all the events from one action method, so you don't need two separate requests, ...

Comment: ... or 3) take advantage of [eventSources](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/eventSources) so you define two separate event functions, one for each AJAX request, and of course each will then have its own separate `callback`, and fullCalendar will listen to both of them.

Comment: IMHO Option 3 is probably the simplest, Option 2 might need the most coding work, but be the most efficient (because less HTTP requests happening), and Option 1 is the cheap and dirty solution, but much less efficient. You need to decide how you want to do it.

Comment: BTW your action methods need to accept the "start" and "end" dates provided by fullCalendar, and they need to filter the data to only return events which fall within those dates. otherwise, as time goes on and you have more historical (and future) data in your system, your AJAX calls will get slower and return more data, most of which no-one will look at. You should only return data which is relevant to the dates the user is looking at. If the user does change to a date where no data has been downloaded yet, fullCalendar will automatically request that from the server at the time it's needed.

Comment: P.S. there is no need to run the `.format` method on your momentJS objects. fullCalendar can accept the moment object directly. It does not need a string. And I dread to think why you need to add extra days to your start and end dates before showing them on the calendar. Is there something wrong with your source data?? (Also it would be quite a lot more efficient if your server would output JSON in the format which fullCalendar recognises, instead of having to parse it all client-side and create new objects.)